# page scroll reaches half way from the end javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code which i am using to load more data when the page scroll reaches the end of scroll.

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()
```

Now i want to load data when the page scroll reaches 3/4th or 1/2 of the complete scroll. What should i change in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do ,for half:

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == ($(document).height() / 2)
```

and for 3/4

```
$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == ( ($(document).height() * 3 ) / 4)
```